# Amazon S3 interface with PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I need to provide a utility on a PHP site for a client to upload files to an amazon S3 bucket.  Are there any open source utilities available that I can use?

ideally, this utility would allow the client to select a local file, press the upload button, and then would tell him the URL of the newly uploaded file.

Bonus points if this can provide a list of existing files to browse through.

Thanks!

*Edit:* This isn't exactly what I'm looking for, but it certainly works as a workaround for now.
http://s3browse.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workaround you're using requires sharing your secret key with a 3rd party web site. Which is highly insecure and simply bad practice.

Why not use S3fm?

http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3fm/index.html

Online, secure, convenient. Runs directly from Amazon S3 - no need to share your secret keys with anyone.

Comment: that's great! hadn't come across it

Comment: Now available at: http://www.s3fm.com/

Comment: Alex, your tool bit address is failing, so no chance contact you about s3fm.  Drop an email to bfschott at gmail.

Comment: s3fm.com is NOT Amazon, but a 3rd party again. I would strongly advise against supplying any 3rd party site with any type of login credentials or private/secret keys.

Comment: Wow.  Yes, this is a little bit alarming.  The advice offered here is don't share your keys with a third party site ... except for this one, with a cleverly-designed url to make it look like an official Amazon product when it is in fact a third party site.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE (july 2014)**: Here is the new official AWS SDK for PHP:

- Github repository: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php
- Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/index.html

---

Amazon provides a PHP SDK for accessing AWS services, including S3.

See on github: [amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php)

See documentation: [AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/), very well done, with a lot of examples.

Answer (score 5):

Plenty available with a quick Google search:

- http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class
- http://code.google.com/p/amazon-s3-php-class/
- http://edoceo.com/creo/phps3tk
- http://tlrobinson.net/blog/2008/04/18/amazon-s3-php-helpers/

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Zend Framework's Amazon components - don't worry they can be used ouside of any other Zend bits and pieces.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html

Comment: Comment for the linked page: "For error responses, Amazon returns a ton of useful information in the response body and this class throws all of it away, making debugging very frustrating. ". Recommendation is to use native AWS sdk (see another answer)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon officially supports [Tarzan AWS](http://tarzan-aws.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using the PHP SDK, which is probably the first best choice, I've used the S3CMD command line tool in both Windows and Ubuntu/Debian environment in the past in various scripts.

http://s3tools.org/s3cmd

Very simple to use and has a "sync" command similar to rsync that makes writing scripts for adding files to S3 perfect.

Tyler

Answer (score 0):

You can use my php + extjs script for uploading files to amazon s3  and explore your bucket.
https://github.com/aliasif/s3explorer

Answer (score 0):

I never found a updated Script with Amazons latest sdk. i have made it by myself. it woks as a php commandline interpreter script. give it a try :

https://github.com/arizawan/aiss3clientphp

Comment: Use link as a comment not as an answer.

Comment: Sorry! i am new in stackoverflow.

Comment: No problem, keep in mind and be careful from next time.